# Questions abous blockchain and ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth

I'm reading about blockchain and started devoloping my first smart contract, i have a lot of experience devoloping IT solutions, but everything in blockchain look very different than what i'm used to, i can't visualize some approach and possible i'm losing something in my reading, if someone could help me with those questions below ...

[image]

:)

so lets go

Suposing i have a blockchain solution running in ethereum. It's a voting system and this system was devoloped by a district to do a research with your citizens so

1. If one of the citizens vote, it's a transacation in ethereum and this must be paid using gas. To do that, you need ether and when you create an account this is zero. How would the citizens vote ? will they need to buy ether in a exchange (or mining ?) ?
2. how can i block votes outside my district if everybody in the network can send data to my smart contract ?
3. Is it common to have a traditional system for store other datas (address, phones, SSI) and use only a particular transaction, like vote, in blockchain ? how can i integrate them ?
4. i have created a wallet in myetherwallet. This wallet is the same as a new account command using geth ? is it possible to connect to my wallet created in myetherwallet from geth ?

where can i find a god material for those topics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below responses from my end. Remember, the more responses we get to these questions the more diverse it can become as ideas differ from one individual to another based on lots of factors. Anyhow, here we go...

1. If one of the citizens vote, it's a transacation in ethereum and this must be paid using gas. To do that, you need ether and when you create an account this is zero. How would the citizens vote ? will they need to buy ether in a exchange (or mining ?) ?

> Yes, for starters they have to pay the gas. Although, there's an [ERC827](https://medium.com/bitclave/do-not-pay-transaction-fees-in-ethereum-21a9dccaaf63) out there not to pay fee, and also some discussions around delegating the payment to a specific account, such that instead of individual users the owner of the smart contract can pay. In this case maybe the government can bear the amount.

2. how can i block votes outside my district if everybody in the network can send data to my smart contract ?

> You can run consortium chain like quorum to limit the participants to a specific group. So that the transactions aren’t visible to everyone. Because on the Blockchain main chain of Ethereum it’s visible to everyone.

3. Is it common to have a traditional system for store other datas (address, phones, SSI) and use only a particular transaction, like vote, in blockchain ? how can i integrate them ?

> Yup, you don't want to take the Personal Information (PI) onto Blockchain as its visible for everyone to view. Instead you can have them store in a database and use an [Oracle](http://www.oraclize.it/) service to be able to talk to outside Blockchain.

4. i have created a wallet in myetherwallet. This wallet is the same as a new account command using geth ? is it possible to connect to my wallet created in myetherwallet from geth ?

> Yes, pretty much possible. You can use your password (or) mnemonic to connect to that account from your geth node.

5. where can i find a god material for those topics ?

> Get this [book on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491971940) or if you are eager to read it before you get the paperback book read it on github [here](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook). A better way to read this as a book on github is install an extension called [Octotree](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/octotree/bkhaagjahfmjljalopjnoealnfndnagc?hl=en-US)

Hope, i have answered your questions, except one :)

Comment: thank you Khaja, you were very helpfully :). By the way, in item 2. Suppose this system are voting an election for USA next president, the question was, how can i block someone from Norway to vote, as blockchain is a public network.

after you answer in item 3, i understand i could get this blocking the foreign users in my system, don't you ?

Comment: You can run consortium chain like quorum to limit the participants to a specific group. So that the transactions aren’t visible to everyone. Because on the Blockchain main chain of Ethereum it’s visible to everyone.

Comment: I have updated the same in my answer as well in the original response.